# How To Calculate A Winding Number?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry

We have a closed curve C on the plane given by parametric equations: x=x(t), y=y(t), t changes between a and b, x and y are smooth functions.
We want to calculate the winding number of this curve around the origin. 
The most natural way to do it is to calculate the path integral:

$$\int_C \frac{-y\,dx+x\,dy}{x^2+y^2}$$

However, this integral turns out to be too complicated to calculate. What should we do now? Are there any efficient and strong methods to quickly and calculate the winding number?

Thanks.

Comment: Without knowing the curve, it is very hard to tell what to do in your case...

Comment: You mean, numerically? It ought to be a question of keeping track of how $(x,y)$ moves from one quadrant to the next – or previous, as the case may be. If you want a rigourous result, you need estimates on derivatives to make sure the curve can't do an undiscovered trip around the origin between time steps.

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen: No it needs to be done analytically.
If you describe a general strategy, it would suffice. (A reference would be great.)

@Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: What about if x(t) and y(t) are polynomials?

Comment: That the computation is done numerically does not necessarily mean that the result is an aproximation; since you know that the result of the integral is an integer, aproximating it with an error less than, say, $1/4$ is enough to know the exact result... 

Comment: @George: Here is an answer related to those already given: Find the sign of $y(t)$ at each zero of $x(t)$, and vice versa.  (For non-pathological curves, there will be only finitely many zeros to check.)  This will tell you which halves of the coordinate axes the curve crosses, and in which order.  You can avoid having to do the "vice versa" if you also determine whether $x(t)$ is increasing or decreasing near each zero of $x(t)$ (say, by using derivatives).

Comment: @ Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: that is true, and I was aware of that. But is there any purely analytic, elegant approach? (I'm not saying 'algorithm', that would be too much to ask.) Something along the lines of transforming the integral, perhaps? Some suggested working with the roots of the functions x(t) and y(t), what about it?

Comment: @Bjorn Poonen: thank you, that's a helpful answer. I see it now. 

Sometimes a problem might occure: what if the roots turn out to be too hard to find? 


Comment: Your question is essentially open-ended, and you are always going to have a problem with a sufficiently evil curve... Unless you make precise what you want, so as to be able to see what an answer would be, this is not a great question, really!

Comment: @George: If the roots are hard to find exactly, then you could try to find them numerically, similarly to the suggestions of Harald and Mariano.  For example, if you show that x(t) has a zero in [a,b] (say, by observing that x(a) and x(b) have opposite signs) and can show that it's unique (say, by showing that x'(t) has constant sign on [a,b]), and you can show that y(t) has constant sign on [a,b], then that tells you the sign of y(t) at the zero of x(t).  If you find intervals like this and show that x(t) does not change sign *between* the intervals, then that tells you all you need to know.


Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: That's fair enough. What I was looking for was to hear about the whole bunch of different approaches and methods, but you are probably right and I should have narrowed it down. 

@ Bjorn Poonen: I get it now, thank you.

Comment: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/299/simultaneous-editing/

Comment: The integral needs to be divided by $2\pi$.

Comment: @Charlie: Yes, but the OP didn't say the integral is the answer, only that one way to get the answer is to compute the integral.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is simple if you can draw a picture of your curve.  Find a direction so that your tangent is always moving as you pass through it. Count the number of tangents pointing in that direction with a sign. +1 if you are moving through the direction counterclockwise, and -1 if you are moving through the direction clockwise. The sum of the +1's and -1's is your winding number.

Answer (score 4):

The following well-known fact may be useful. If you continuously deform C into another loop C' without crossing the origin, then C' has the same winding number. (And the converse is true.)

In particular, you can reduce your problem to calculating the degree of a mapping S<sup>1</sup> → S<sup>1</sup>.

Certainly, it's far from a general recipe.